# FFMPEG: How do I output appended log files for Audio (silencedetect) and Video (blackdetect) Monitoring of a UDP Stream (not an MP4 file)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, udp

I am outputting log files for both audio and video monitoring for a UDP stream showing silencedetect and blackdetect.  I have working code for both however I can't seem to get **grep** to filter only relevant data for the logs in video or audio.  Here is what I have so far.

**AUDIO CODE**

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://@232.1.1.5:30120" -af silencedetect=n=-20dB:d=0.1 -f null - 2>&1 | grep silencedetect >> audio_silence_udp.txt
```

**AUDIO LOG audio_silence_udp.txt Sample Output**

```
frame=   73 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.67 bitrate=N/A speed=6.87x    
frame=  167 fps=159 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.80 bitrate=N/A speed=6.48x    
frame=  182 fps=117 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.30 bitrate=N/A speed= 4.7x    
frame=  197 fps= 96 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.80 bitrate=N/A speed= 3.8x    
frame=  212 fps= 83 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.30 bitrate=N/A speed=3.25x    
frame=  227 fps= 74 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.80 bitrate=N/A speed=2.88x    
frame=  242 fps= 68 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.30 bitrate=N/A speed=2.62x    
frame=  258 fps= 64 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.84 bitrate=N/A speed=2.42x    
frame=  273 fps= 60 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.34 bitrate=N/A speed=2.26x    
frame=  288 fps= 57 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.84 bitrate=N/A speed=2.13x    
frame=  303 fps= 54 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.34 bitrate=N/A speed=2.03x    
frame=  318 fps= 52 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.84 bitrate=N/A speed=1.94x    
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 11.1646
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 11.2966 | silence_duration: 0.132
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 11.6126
frame=  333 fps= 51 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.34 bitrate=N/A speed=1.87x    
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 11.7766 | silence_duration: 0.164
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 11.9966
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 12.1926 | silence_duration: 0.196
frame=  348 fps= 49 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.84 bitrate=N/A speed=1.81x    
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 12.4447
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 12.6087 | silence_duration: 0.164
```

**AUDIO LOG SHOULD BE**

```
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 11.1646
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 11.2966 | silence_duration: 0.132
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 11.6126
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 11.7766 | silence_duration: 0.164
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 11.9966
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 12.1926 | silence_duration: 0.196
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_start: 12.4447
[silencedetect @ 0x55d604a79fa0] silence_end: 12.6087 | silence_duration: 0.164
```

**VIDEO CODE**

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://@232.1.1.5:30120" -vf "blackdetect=d=.2:pix_th=0.00" -an -f null - 2>&1 | grep blackdetect >> video_black.txt
```

**VIDEO LOG**

```
frame= 3660 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:02.32 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3675 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:02.82 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3691 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:03.35 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3707 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:03.89 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3722 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:04.39 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3738 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:04.92 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3753 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:05.42 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3768 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:05.92 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
[blackdetect @ 0x5632d20b58e0] black_start:124.598 black_end:125.966 black_duration:1.36811
frame= 3782 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:06.39 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3799 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:06.96 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3815 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:07.49 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3830 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:07.99 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x    
frame= 3845 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:08.49 bitrate=N/A speed=1.04x
```

**VIDEO LOG SHOULD BE**

```
[blackdetect @ 0x5632d20b58e0] black_start:124.598 black_end:125.966 black_duration:1.36811
```

Comment: Use the metadata filter to print to stdout as per my answer in your last Q.

Comment: That answer returned an error: Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@232.1.1.5:30120' Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x5581c8e8dde0] Option 'direct' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5581c88e6100] Error initializing filter 'ametadata' with args 'print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=log.txt:direct=1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!

Comment: The problem I am having now is with grep the previous question no longer applies.  This problem may be related to piping to grep, I'm not sure.  Thank you for any help you can give me.